# Datasource name for a local Oracle Docker Instance

Tags: oracle, docker, local

I am trying to connect to an oracle docker instance through a framework. The framework requires the table name and logical host name to be passed in.

I am able to connect to the docker instance using jdbc connection in java.

My question is how do i set the logical host name to this docker instance that i can use.

Things I have tried:

- I tried by adding a logical host in /etc/hosts file in the image
  using docker run command.
- I tried passing in the docker name as the logical host
- I tried giving the host name mentioned in tnsnames.ora file in the image

I am using Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90 and Oracle v12.2.0.1. Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to containerize the application that uses that framework? If you put all the containers in the same stack, using docker-compose or docker stack, you'll be able to reach each one of the services through the service name.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Creating an Oracle Database Docker image](https://geraldonit.com/2017/08/21/creating-an-oracle-database-docker-image/) blog for more details.